# Formatting for body of \item in itemize/enumerate/description environment

Tags: formatting, lists, enumitem

What I am looking for is a way to specify some formatting, say italics, for the body of each `\item` in an itemize/enumerate/description environment, up front, without having to do it explicitly for each item. Moreover, I want no formatting for the Labels. This is what I want:

[image]

And here is my code sample:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\textit{\begin{itemize}[font=\normalfont]
 \item[Label 1:] Item 1
 \item[Label 2:] Item 2
 \item[Label 3:] Item 3
\end{itemize}}

\end{document}
```

Is this a good way of doing it or is there a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To setup any list environment the package [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem/) is a very good choice.

The package provides the key `before` where you can execute any code. If you set `\itshape` this will influence the whole inclusive of the labels. So you have to set the font of the labels by `\normalfont`.

This leads to:

```
\begin{itemize}[before=\itshape,font=\normalfont]
```

This method is recommend to setup one list.

Modifying all lists maybe separate by the type you can use the command `\setlist`

The following line sets every label to `\normalfont` whereby the body font will be italics.

```
\setlist{before=\itshape,font=\normalfont}
```

If you want to specify the environment you can use the optional argument of `\setlist`

```
\setlist[itemize]{before=\itshape,font=\normalfont}
```

The command `\setlist` allows much more. For example the specifying of the influenced depth.

I recommend to have a look at the [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem/) which also provides a lot of examples.

Comment: It may also be advisable, based on the original MWE, to use `\begin{enumerate}[before=\itshape,font=\normalfont,label=Label~\arabic*:]` instead of `itemize`.

Comment: @Werner: Indeed. But I don't know whether `Label 1` is only an example or not ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Thanks for the information. Actually I have been goinf through the documentation for enumitem before making this post. What I find strange is that the general syntax as well as any description of the commands \setlist and \newlist are missing from the manual. The author randomly introduces the commands at the end of Page 2. Could you provide some more information on the general syntax for the two commands?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Sorry, my bad. The commands are defined at the end. The overall content of the package is a bit disorganized; hence my troubles in finding what I was looking for

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I asked another question about a month back but got no replies. I reposted the question today. Here is the link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64414/15006

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: @Chatterjee: David was faster ;-)