# \multirow and \bigstrut[b] not working together

Tags: multirow

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}

    \newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X R}

    Column 1 & Column 2 \\ \hline

    1.1 & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{2a} \bigstrut[t] \\
    1.2 &     \bigstrut[b] \\ \hline 

    1.3 & \multirow{3}[2]{*}{2b} \bigstrut[t] \\
    1.4 &   \\
    1.5 &   \bigstrut[b] \\ \hline

    1.6 & 2c \bigstrut \\ \hline

    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The output for this code I'm getting is:
[image]

My question is:

Notice how in the 1st two sections, viz. 2a and 2b, \bigstrut[b] is adding an extra amount of space when used in conjunction with \multirow. I checked some table tutorials online where they make use of this same construct, yet with no difficulty! Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you should normally put anything other than the `\multirow` arguments in the initial cell, nor anything at all in the cells that are spanned. Also you need a `\noindent` before the table so that the full width table fits on a line.

I don't know if this is the layout you wanted but it doesn't have the big gaps. I just moved the struts to the first column.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}

    \newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X R}

    Column 1 & Column 2 \\ \hline

    1.1\bigstrut[t] & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{2a} \\
    1.2\bigstrut[b] &     \\ \hline 

    1.3\bigstrut[t] & \multirow{3}[2]{*}{2b} \\
    1.4 &   \\
    1.5\bigstrut[b] &   \\ \hline

    1.6\bigstrut & 2c \\ \hline

    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Following your advice, how would I incorporate struts in a table where all \multirow is used for all rows?

Comment: You can put struts _into_ the text of the multirow cell eg a tt] strut at the start and a [b] strut at the end, (but I'm not sure why you need struts at all, the basic latex array code puts them in already and if you want to make them bigger you can use `\arraystretch` as all that does is make the struts bigger