# description environment with italic, non bold labels, bullets and normal font in the description

Tags: formatting, lists, itemize, enumitem, description

I think I am lost in something very easy with the `enumitem` package.

I would like a description environment where the label is in italics and the description in normal text.

I tried this

```
\documentclass[english,12pt,a4paper,pdftex]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\setlist{before=\normalfont,font=\itshape} 

\begin{description}
\item [point-referenced data] this should be in normal font
\item [areal data]
\item [point pattern data]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

problem is for some reasons the label comes out in bold italic and I do not why.
Is it lso possible to add bullets to it?

Summarizing I would like to have a description environment with italic, non bold labels, bullets and normal font in the description.

Before you ask I checked [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64413/formatting-for-body-of-item-in-itemize-enumerate-description-environment) and numerous others, but I do not understand how to make all the options work together.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: done, sorry, too minimal example I guess :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You don't need the `before` key; just revert to `\normalfont` for the label and apply `\itshape`; by using `[description]` as optional argument to `\setlist` only this environment will be affected.

For the bullet, you can easily do it by slightly abusing the `font` key:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\setlist[description]{font=\normalfont\itshape\textbullet\space}

\begin{description}
\item [point-referenced data] this should be in normal font
\item [areal data]
\item [point pattern data]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Don't use the `pdftex` option. It just limits portability and is useless as the packages using it are able to infer it automatically.

[image]