# bulletpoints - setting distance between the first word and the rest of sentence

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize, bullets

I have a text which I wrote in word and now I want to transfer it to Latex. In the bulletpoints I have two problems.

1- I cannot set a constant spacing between the symbols and the explanations (See figure)

2- I cannot tell Latex to continue below the explanation if the sentence goes in two lines.

The following image shows what I want:

[image]

My code at present is:

```
\begin{itemize}
\setlength\itemsep{0em}
\item  $p_{3} (\lambda)$ : \tab \tab is the spectrally resolved power density after reflection in glass$ \vert $ polymer interface once 

\item  \( P_{3}: \) \tab \tab is the power loss in glass due to reflection in glass$ \vert $ polymer interface once\

\item  \(  \Delta P_{rel.f_{3}}: \) \tab \tab is the relative power loss reflected on the glass$ \vert $ polymer interface once

\item  \( p_{4} \left(  \lambda  \right) : \) \tab \tab is the spectrally resolved power density after absorption in polymer once

\item  \( P_{4}: \) \tab \tab is the power loss in glass due to absorption in polymer once

\item  \(  \Delta P_{rel.f_{4}}: \) \tab \tab is the relative power loss absorbed by the polymer once
\end{itemize}{}
```

my Latex results looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us how `\tab` is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're better off using a `tabular`-type setup instead of an `itemize` setup. The answer shown below employs a `tabularx` environment of overall width `\textwidth`; the width of the second column is computed by LaTeX as the residual.

The `tabularx` environments are constructed twice below -- the first time with leading text bullets, the second time without. Personally, I don't think that the text bullets are even necessary.

The width of the intercolumn whitespace is governed by the parameter `\tabcolsep`; its default value in most document classes is `6pt`. Feel free to change it, via `\setlength` and/or `\addtolength` statements.

Note that I've also replaced all instances of `$\vert$` with `\slash`, as I believe that the `/` separator is more easily read and understood.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=RaggedRight,
              singlelinecheck=false,
              skip=0.5\baselineskip}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\caption{Workflow of the spectrally resolved optical model and\dots}
\textbf{Nomenclature}

\medskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\textbullet\ }l L @{}}
$p_{3} (\lambda)$ & spectrally resolved power density after reflection in glass\slash polymer interface once \\ 
$P_{3}$ & power loss in glass due to reflection in glass\slash polymer interface once\\
$\Delta P_{\mathit{rel.f}_{3}}$ & relative power loss reflected on the glass\slash polymer interface once\\
$p_{4}(\lambda)$ & spectrally resolved power density after absorption in polymer once\\
$P_{4}$ & power loss in glass due to absorption in polymer once\\
$\Delta P_{\mathit{rel.f}_{4}}$ & relative power loss absorbed by the polymer once
\end{tabularx}
\end{figure}

%% second solution: same as the first, except no text bullets
\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{Same material, but without text bullets}
\textbf{Nomenclature}

\medskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l L @{}}
$p_{3} (\lambda)$ & spectrally resolved power density after reflection in glass\slash polymer interface once \\ 
$P_{3}$ & power loss in glass due to reflection in glass\slash polymer interface once\\
$\Delta P_{\mathit{rel.f}_{3}}$ & relative power loss reflected on the glass\slash polymer interface once\\
$p_{4}(\lambda)$ & spectrally resolved power density after absorption in polymer once\\
$P_{4}$ & power loss in glass due to absorption in polymer once\\
$\Delta P_{\mathit{rel.f}_{4}}$ & relative power loss absorbed by the polymer once
\end{tabularx}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and the tips. It works perfectly. I am sorry that I cannot vote for the post while my reputations in Tex is not enough. Please accepts my thanks here.

Answer (score 2):

With `description` environment, using `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{description}[font=\normalfont\textbullet\space,%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149187/
                        leftmargin=6em, labelsep=0em, labelwidth=6em]
\item[$p_{3}(\lambda)$:] is the spectrally resolved power density after reflection in glass$ \vert $ polymer interface once

\item[$P_{3}$:] is the power loss in glass due to reflection in glass$ \vert $ polymer interface once\

\item[$\Delta P_{rel.f_{3}}$:] is the relative power loss reflected on the glass$ \vert $ polymer interface once

\item[$p_{4}(\lambda)$:] is the spectrally resolved power density after absorption in polymer once

\item[$P_{4}$:] is the power loss in glass due to absorption in polymer once

\item[$\Delta P_{rel.f_{4}}$:] is the relative power loss absorbed by the polymer once
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the extra alternative for the previous solution. sorry I did not vote up while I do not have enough reputations yet.

Answer (score 2):

I propose another solution, defining a new environment based on `description`, with the help of package `eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{mynomencl}{%
\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{%
\hspace\labelsep \eqmakebox[DL][l]{\textbullet\quad ##1}}\description[font=\normalfont, leftmargin=\dimexpr\eqboxwidth{DL} + \labelsep]}%
{\enddescription}

\begin{document}

\begin{mynomencl}
\item[$p_{3} (\lambda)$ :] is the spectrally resolved power density after reflection in glass$ \vert $ polymer interface once

\item[\( P_{3}: \)] is the power loss in glass due to reflection in glass$ \vert $ polymer interface once\

\item[\( \Delta P_{rel.f_{3}}: \)] is the relative power loss reflected on the glass$ \vert $ polymer interface once

\item[\( p_{4} \left( \lambda \right) : \)] is the spectrally resolved power density after absorption in polymer once

\item[\( P_{4}: \)] is the power loss in glass due to absorption in polymer once

\item[\( \Delta P_{rel.f_{4}}: \)] is the relative power loss absorbed by the polymer once
\end{mynomencl}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the alternative. due to the less reputations, I cannot vote up.

Comment: That is quite unimportant!